# pyhton-pkcs11 package in 16.04

Tags: python, 16.04, python-2.7

I see that pyhton-pkcs11 isn't included in 16.04 repositories. Only pyhton3-pkcs11. Is there any way to install Python2 package version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install it with pip:

```
pip install pyhton-pkcs11
```

But you need build dependencies:
 `debhelper, swig, python-dev`

Comment: debhelper, swig, python-dev installed ok.  But when I run the pip command I got the following errors:
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
The folder you are executing pip from can no longer be found.

Comment: then I tried with sudo, then sudo -E and the error continued. I couldn't find any web references on this subject.

Comment: Restart of system.

Comment: Did it. Now I got: Collecting python-pykcs11
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-pykcs11 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-pykcs11

Comment: So open bug: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pykcs11/1.2.1

Comment: You can install package from another distro/version but it can break the python.

Comment: Yes I know. And this is a software many people use. I have to find a normal way of doing things :)

Comment: I found it... it was the package name... it's noy pyhton-pkcs11 it's just pkcs11. Then pyhton- prefix is in .deb packages only.

Comment: And my application worked. Thanks for your help. Helped a lot! :)